# Is it possible to use stroke width from kind of variable?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Here is the problem. We do have project in AI where objects are stroked. For now we assume that objects will have stroke 2px.

However we can change our mind and want all strokes to be 3px - and we want to avoid changing it for each separate object. Is there a way to define this number and change value later so all strokes will be updated?

Comment: Select all and change the stroke width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select one object with a stroke on an artboard..

then choose..... `Select > Same > Stroke Weight`

This will allow you to quickly select *all objects with the same stroke weight* and change it, regardless of actual stroke color.

Comment: Not exactly what I imagined but perfect solution for my project!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, its just not very comfortable. The standard way is to just select all or select same and then change the value. However this said it is possible to define strokes for layers here is how:

1. Select the ball shape next to the layer name in layers palette
2. In appearances panel click on add new stroke stroke
3. then draw your artwork on the layer without any stroke.

You can now select the layer ball again and change the stroke. Its a bit painfull so i dont use it often but it does work.